# Specify Python version when cloning base conda environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda3

I am trying to create a Python 2 environment on Anaconda3 that clones all of the packages from the base environment. I know that `conda create --name myenv --clone base` creates a clone using the currently acquired version of Python, but is there a way to specify the version when doing this?

So far I have tried specifying the version like `conda create --name test_env --clone base python=2.7` but got the error
`TooManyArgumentsError: did not expect any arguments for --clone Got 1 argument (python=2.7) but expected 0.`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to clone the base in this case.  For example, I installed the latest Anaconda with version 3.9, but not everything works with it, I needed  Python 3.8.

This worked for me:

```
conda create -n "py38" python=3.8 anaconda
```

From below, you can see that it worked:
[image]